# Pytorch batch indexing

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, batch-processing

So the output of my network looks like this:

```
output = tensor([[[ 0.0868, -0.2623],
     [ 0.0716, -0.2668],
     [ 0.0584, -0.2549],
     [ 0.0482, -0.2386],
     [ 0.0410, -0.2234],
     [ 0.0362, -0.2111],
     [ 0.0333, -0.2018],
     [ 0.0318, -0.1951],
     [ 0.0311, -0.1904],
     [ 0.0310, -0.1873],
     [ 0.0312, -0.1851],
     [ 0.0315, -0.1837],
     [ 0.0318, -0.1828],
     [ 0.0322, -0.1822],
     [ 0.0324, -0.1819],
     [ 0.0327, -0.1817],
     [ 0.0328, -0.1815],
     [ 0.0330, -0.1815],
     [ 0.0331, -0.1814],
     [ 0.0332, -0.1814],
     [ 0.0333, -0.1814],
     [ 0.0333, -0.1814],
     [ 0.0334, -0.1814],
     [ 0.0334, -0.1814],
     [ 0.0334, -0.1814]],

    [[ 0.0868, -0.2623],
     [ 0.0716, -0.2668],
     [ 0.0584, -0.2549],
     [ 0.0482, -0.2386],
     [ 0.0410, -0.2234],
     [ 0.0362, -0.2111],
     [ 0.0333, -0.2018],
     [ 0.0318, -0.1951],
     [ 0.0311, -0.1904],
     [ 0.0310, -0.1873],
     [ 0.0312, -0.1851],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164]],

    [[ 0.0868, -0.2623],
     [ 0.0716, -0.2668],
     [ 0.0584, -0.2549],
     [ 0.0482, -0.2386],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164]],

    [[ 0.0868, -0.2623],
     [ 0.0716, -0.2668],
     [ 0.0584, -0.2549],
     [ 0.0482, -0.2386],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164]],

    [[ 0.0868, -0.2623],
     [ 0.0716, -0.2668],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164]],

    [[ 0.0868, -0.2623],
     [ 0.0716, -0.2668],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164]],

    [[ 0.0868, -0.2623],
     [ 0.0716, -0.2668],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164]],

    [[ 0.0868, -0.2623],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164],
     [ 0.1003, -0.2164]]])
```

Which is a shape of `[8, 24, 2]`
Now 8 is my batch size. And i would like to get a data point from every batch, at the following locations:

```
index = tensor([24, 10,  3,  3,  1,  1,  1,  0])
```

So the 24th value from the first batch, the 10th value from the second batch, and so on.

Now i have problems figuring out the syntax. 
I've tried

```
torch.gather(output, 0, index)
```

But it keeps telling me, that my dimensions don't match.
And trying

```
output[ : ,index]
```

Just gets me the values at all the indexes for each batch. 
What would be the correct syntax here, to get these values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To select only one element per batch you need to enumerate the batch indices, which can be done easily with [`torch.arange`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.arange).

```py
output[torch.arange(output.size(0)), index]
```

That essentially creates tuples between the enumerated tensor and your `index` tensor to access the data, which results in indexing `output[0, 24]`, `output[1, 10]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

First a small note, for an output shape [8, 24, 2], the largest index on the secoond dimention can be 23, so I'm modifying your indexes to be

```
index = torch.tensor([23, 10,  3,  3,  1,  1,  1,  0])
output = torch.randn((8,24,2)) # Toy data to represent your output
```

The simplest solution is to use a for loop

```
data_pts = torch.zeros((8,2)) # Tensor to store desired values

for i,j in enumerate(index):
    data_pts[i, :] = output[i, j, :]
```

However, if you want to vectorize the indexing, you simply need indices for all dimensions. For example,

```
data_pts_vectorized = output[range(8), index, :]
```

Since your index vector is in order, you can generate the first dimension index with `range`.

You can confirm that the two approaches have the same results

```
assert(torch.all(data_pts == data_pts_vectorized))
```